# Asm program... something goes wrong

Tags: debugging, assembly, mips

I load two arrays. I have to return a third array that contain the sum of the two and has the dimension of the smaller. Print the last one.

Example:

> INPUT: Array1: [1 2 3 4 5]      Array2: [2 6 1]
>
> OUTPUT: Array3: [3 8 4]

Program runs... it give me the exact number of elements but every element is 0.

```
.data
vett1: .word 0:100  
vett2: .word 0:100          
vett3: .word 0:100  
x: .word 0 
space: .asciiz " "  

.text
.globl main

main:

la $a0, vett1           
la $a1, vett2       
la $a2, vett3       
la $a3, x
li $t0, 0       
li $t1, 0       
li $t2, 0       
jal loadA1  #mi salvo 26 salto a caricavettore1
jal loadA2  #mi salvo 27 salto a caricavettore2
jal lenght  #mi salvo 28 salto a controllalunghezza
lw $t2, ($a3)
lw $t3, ($a3)
la $a0, vett1
la $a1, vett2
la $a2, vett3
jal summ
jal print
li $v0, 10
syscall

loadA1:
li $v0, 5
syscall
beq $v0, -1, exit
sw $v0, ($a0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
addi $a0, $a0, 4
j loadA1
exit: jr $ra

loadA2:
li $v0, 5
syscall
beq $v0, -1, exit2
addi $t1, $t1, 1
sw $v0, ($a1)
addi $a1, $a1, 4
j loadA2
exit2: jr $ra

lenght:
blt $t0, $t1, cond1 
sw $t1, ($a3)       
jr $ra          
cond1:  sw $t0, ($a3)
jr $ra

summ:
subi $sp, $sp, 4    
sw $ra, 0($sp)      
bnez $t2, rec       
j exit3

rec:    lw $s0, ($a0)
lw $s1, ($a1)       
add $v0, $s0, $s1   
sw $v0, ($a2)       
addi $a0, $a0, 4    
addi $a1, $a1, 4    
addi $a2, $a2, 4 
subi $t2, $t2, 1    
jal summ

exit3:
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra

print:
beqz $t3, exit4     
lw $a0, ($a2)       
li $v0, 1
syscall
la $a0, space
li $v0, 4
syscall
addi $a2, $a2, 4
subi $t3, $t3, 1
j print
exit4: jr $ra
```

Comment: Why is the `sum` function recursive? An iterative solution would have been simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sum the two arrays you add 4 to `$a2` at the end of each iteration to point it to the next element of `vett3`. So after the summing is complete `$a2` will point to the first memory location *after* the end of `vett3`.
Then you call `print` but don't reset `$a2` to point at the start of `vett3`, so you end up printing garbage data (which could happen to be all zeroes - or mostly zeroes at least, since `x` and `space` will be there).